# What is this signal (video from O'scope)?

Tags: arduino, pwm, oscilloscope

As the subject implies I need help identifying the waveform on [this video link below](https://youtu.be/reajbcLb2po) (and possibly recreating it later).

The signal is the feed to a John Deere hydraulic solenoid. The signal and return wires were connected to a load resistor with the same value as the solenoid for testing purposes (5.5 ohms).

I was expecting it to be PWM and it looks more like a rectified sine wave that increases in voltage and decreases in frequency as the joystick is pulled further back (more power).

I am trying to take control of the hydraulic solenoid with an Arduino and MOSFET (or similiar) and I would like to use a similar signal as what John Deere uses. PWM works ok to control the solenoid but I am now curious what John Deere is doing and why.

Any help is appreciated!

Video starts with solenoid getting full power. Then the power is varied by moving the joystick back and forth.

Low power signal frequency is ~22kHz 
Low power voltage is from 0 to ~10V
High power signal frequency is ~20kHz.
High power voltage is from ~2.5-10V

Comment: Looks like a filtered PWM signal to me.

Comment: your solenoid may have 5 ohm DC resistance, but it will also have significant inductance. Waveforms into an inductive load will likely differ from a pure resistive load. Sure looks like PWM.

Comment: Thanks! i agree that the waveform connected to the solenoid would differ from a purely resistive load but i was not connected to the solenoid when i took the reading. Im thinking if i recreate the waveform imposed on the resistor, it should do the same thing once it is connected to the actual solenoid. is this a foolish assumption? I mean I suppose  there may be some sort of inductance or capacitance that im not seeing with the resistive load...

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the video to your post. If the video gets removed in the future your question is useless for the community.

Answer (score 1):

The shape of the waveform looks irrelevant to me as well as the changes in voltage and there is no apparent change in duty cycle or slope in the triangular wave other than peak compression.

So my conclusion is that the pulse frequency is modulated for actuator control with a coefficient of -10% of center frequency for full scale.   There must be some accurate frequency reference and there was some disturbing amount of AM & FM noise on the capture signal which may have been procedural setup related.

Suggestion;

Use a PFM signal circuit to control the hydraulics. with ~10% range.

- 22kHz low power
- 20kHz high power

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6cxWt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[Java Simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%201e-8%2022.512744558455275%2056%205%2050%0A183%20176%20224%20256%20224%200%200.5%201.66%203.33%0Ar%20176%20192%20256%20192%200%20100000%0A174%20144%20160%20176%20224%200%2010000%200.23270000000000002%2010k%0Aw%20144%20224%20176%20224%200%0Ac%20144%20224%20144%20272%200%203.3e-10%202.3897310953745285%0Ag%20144%20272%20144%20288%200%0Aw%20256%20224%20256%20192%200%0At%20320%20192%20368%20192%200%201%20-1.9333168044574873%200.6065476044357365%20100%0At%20368%20208%20400%20208%200%201%20-2.539864408893224%200.721925617356777%20100%0At%20320%20256%20368%20256%200%20-1%203.0666831955425127%201.4440447397111966%20100%0At%20368%20240%20400%20240%200%20-1%201.622638455831316%20-0.11557151791868314%20100%0Aw%20400%20224%20432%20224%200%0Ar%20432%20224%20480%20224%200%205%0Ag%20480%20224%20480%20288%200%0AR%20368%20144%20368%20112%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20368%20144%20368%20176%200%0Aw%20368%20176%20400%20176%200%0Aw%20400%20192%20400%20176%200%0Aw%20368%20272%20400%20272%200%0Aw%20400%20272%20400%20256%200%0Ag%20368%20304%20368%20320%200%0Aw%20320%20192%20320%20224%200%0Aw%20320%20224%20320%20256%200%0Ar%20256%20224%20320%20224%200%201000%0Ac%20320%20256%20320%20304%200%201e-8%203.0666831955425127%0Aw%20368%20272%20368%20304%200%0Aw%20368%20304%20320%20304%200%0Ax%20184%20148%20341%20151%200%2014%20Choose%20correct%20V%205~12V%0Ax%20180%20275%20275%20278%200%2014%201%25%20NPO%20(pref)%0Ao%206%2064%200%204107%205%200.00009765625%200%202%206%203%0Ao%203%2064%200%204099%205%200.00009765625%200%202%203%203%0Ao%2024%2064%200%204098%205%200.00625%201%202%2024%203%0Ao%2011%2064%200%204098%205%200.4%202%202%2011%203%0A)

This is for testing purposes only but give 20~22kHz approx.

Choose 10A power output transistor and 12V or less according to your results.

Comment: Tony - wow! This is exactly the kind of advice i was looking for. I am going to try to duplicate this triangle wave with an arduino uno and a bit-bang a DAC then run the output to a power op-amp voltage follower. Do you foresee any issues with this approach?

Comment: There are simpler ways depending on frequency error tolerance, that you must figure out.  Start with a variable frequency Schmitt Inverter oscillator and complementary emitter follower driver and test for voltage impedance and frequency. I doubt if waveform is critical, but we do not know approx L value of 5.5 Ohm load, I'll add to my answer

Comment: This is fantastic. Yet again great advice. Even though I don't want to sound like a total novice Im going to ask anyway. How do I get the voltage across the load to get to get it up to around 10v? In all fairness I haven't been able to play with the simulation much because I am with my father in the hospital at the moment. If you tell me to go study the circuit and come back I will! I was just curious if it was something easy - tried increasing the voltage feeding the emitter follower to no avail. This is why I became an EE. Not industrial instrumentation, maintenance, and substation problems.

Comment: Also is q1 supposed to be in cutoff mode for the whole waveform? If I take them out they don't change the output. Is this right?

Comment: I did not  see the voltage on your waveform, so you decide what supply is needed.  Q1 is only to pull down if there is reactive load as well which can store voltage or current, otherwise not needed if pure R, but I have no idea what the load is.  A solenoid doesn't respond to FM but maybe average DC voltage.  Measure again. It may have just been a PFM DC boost regulator and the waveform was just ripple and I could not see the DC rise clearly. Better measurements needed with real load with a variable DC source.